# Nexus 7 - Stuck on boot animation. Fastboot detects device but ADB doesn't

Tags: adb, backup, unbricking, fastboot

My Nexus 7 (2012, WiFi) is stuck on the boot animation. I can detect it in Fastboot but not with ADB. Is it still possible to backup the data before I wipe it?
It's not rooted and the bootloader is locked.

Comment: Can you boot into Recovery?